# C++ to Delphi convert. `this` pointer

Tags: c++, delphi, this

In C++:

```
static_cast<unsigned int>(reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>(&this[-0x00003111]))
```

I don't understand `&this[-0x00003111]`

I can't understand "[-address]"

How to convert it to delphi code?

Comment: What don't you understand? Taking the address? Array indexing? What this is? Do you know any C++? If not you need to learn enough to understand the code and SO isn't a substitute for that.

Comment: It's UB to `reinterpret_cast` from a class type to `unsigned int`, so strictly the meaning of that code is **anything at all**

Comment: @Caleth: I bet that this only works in a certain implementation, and the author knows that at offset -0x3111 (times 4) there is something he or she wants to know the value of. So it may UB, but this looks like a hack, so UB is not so important. **But ISTM that this can't simply be translated to a language like Delphi, which has a totally different structure, anyway.** This question is unanswerable, unless we know what the piece of code is supposed to achieve.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis don't you mean "offset -0x3111 (times `sizeof(decltype(*this))`)" It's **also UB** if this is being run on something that's not (at least) the 0x3112th element of an array

Comment: @Caleth: I mean "times 4". **UB is not relevant here**, as this is a specific pice of code for a specific implementation of a specific class on a specific platform. **This is a hack**. It doesn't matter if this is the 0x3112th element of an array or not. Here, the code simply accesses the address that is 0xC444 below the address pointed to by `this` (very likely part of the VMT of the class). That is not portable or even standard compliant, of course. But hacks seldom are.

Comment: @Caleth: and this is a 32 bit platform where pointer and uint have the same size. That is the main reason the hack works. It can't work when uint is not the same size as a pointer. So I am pretty sure that sizeof(decltype(*this)) is 4.

Comment: No. I dont use hack. Just i Know what this code. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange piece of code. To understand this the [operator precedences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) have to be considered.

However, the important missing piece is the `class` to which `this` refers to. I assume this happens in a method of `class A`. The following code does the same like

```
static_cast<unsigned int>(reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>(&this[-0x00003111]))
```

but with separated expressions:

```
A *pThis = this;
A &a = pThis[-0x00003111]; // aka. A &a = *(pThis - 0x00003111);
A *pA = &a;
unsigned int ui = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>(pA);
unsigned int ui2 = static_cast<unsigned int>(ui);
```

(To get this compiling at all, I had to use `-fpermissive`.)

Considering that 64 bit CPUs are very common nowadays, may be, it is worth to mention that the `unsigned int` may have 32 bits only where the `this` pointer has 64 bit in this case. So, the `reinterpret_cast` clips half of the bits away in this case.

<kbd>[**Life Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb51692b77e23c81)</kbd>

**Dear children.**

Please, don't do this at home.

Comment: this does not look like pascal ... IIRC at least all the `=` should be `:=` but havent use pascal for decades

Comment: @Spektre Well, this is the 1st part of the answer - explaining what this C++ expression does mean. Concerning the 2nd part - how to translate this to Delphi - I've asked a friend who does professional work in Delphi (but he resides on the other side of earth and probably sleeps currently). May be, he helps me to provide the 2nd part...

Comment: The code in the Q is most definitely a terrible hack. It may work in a certain implementation of C++, but it is very, very unlikely to achieve the exact same in Delphi, where classes may have a totally different structure.

Comment: @Spektre: of course that was not Delphi or Pascal. It was the explanation of what the piece of C++ code does, or tries to do.

Comment: To add to may previous comment: *if this was C++Builder, it may be possible. ISTM it possibly tries to read offset -0x3111 (times the size of an uint) of the VMT of a Delphi-compatible C++ class (or even a Delphi class), which C++Builder can generate.* So without more knowledge, this Q is unanswerable.

Comment: Thankyou kind Explanation. I cant understand code . But now i understand code . I dont use hack. Just i want know this code . Because i study 32bit Processing. This code like hack. I searching google and find this code. But i dont ise this code and dont use this code for hack . Just understand